# Does a generative grammar of the English language exist?

Tags: generative-grammar, phrase-structure

Is there some database on the internet that contains generative grammar of the English language / or any natural language?

I know there are many artificial languages like EBNF those can be formalized as generative grammars, but I think this is a lot harder for a natural language.

Can be Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar as well.

Comment: Do you mean a complete grammar, or a fragment of a grammar. If the former, no. If the latter, there are some.

Comment: No. -----------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there has never been a truly complete description of English (or any natural language) in generative terms—or in any formal system, in fact. Such a thing would be wonderfully useful, but all that exists at present are effectively fragments, covering a small subset of the language.